# Android Push Notifications through Google Cloud Messaging for Titanium

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, google-cloud-messaging

If anybody knows how to implement Android push notifications through Google Cloud Messaging in Titanium mobile development, please provide me with some help.

Advance Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check this titanium-module which integrate GCM with your app https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-/

am still trying to figure out how it work, but it look like many people is using it and its working fine ..

PS : i have tested it with one of my application and its working like a charm for over a week .. but you need to be careful about how to design your application notifications work

Comment: @zahrg: Now as google has moved to Firebase Cloud Messaging what is the way to integrate Push Notifications into Android Appcelerator app using above module?

Comment: @Wikki I dont think this module will work any more, as you can see its 4y old, but why not to check https://github.com/chrisribe/ti-firebase it *may* work.